# How do I reference constants in a PHP file from a different PHP file?

Tags: php

I was doing a tutorial on accessing databases with PHP and in  one file, `db_const.php`, I was instructed to make constants like so:

```
<?php
    # mysql db constants DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME
    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    const DB_USER = 'TestUser';
    const DB_PASS = 'TestPass';
    const DB_NAME = 'TestName';
?>
```

But when I run the script that references the constants, I get the following error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' in
>   /var/www/sites/xxx/login.php on line 17

Comment: [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file (before the code using it)

Comment: What does login.php look like?

Comment: you use 'define', not 'const',  save those codes to a file, maybe called 'config.php', and require('config.php') at the top of any file need it.

Comment: @Jacob Thank you! Any wisdom to share on `require()` versus `require_once()`?

Comment: @8protons If you require multiple times the same resources, require_one will ensure it will be loaded only once.

Comment: @Jacob Thank you, I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just **include** it , eg :

```
include('db_const.php') // or `require` but this one stops the script if the required script is missed
```

Comment: Thank you, Akram! Right before I saw this, I found `require_once()`

Comment: the **_once** constraint only help to prevent multiple inclusions pal and glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

In `login.php`, use the following:

```
require_once("db_const.php");
```